# Purpose of Bus to Bus Entry (Kicad [Eeschema])

Tags: kicad, bus, schematic

On the far right of Eeschema, there is a button below Wire to Bus Entry: Bus to Bus Entry.

What is the purpose of this, and how can it be used?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It serves no purpose other than a 45° aesthetic.  It has been removed in KiCad version 6 and replaced with a bus element of similar orientation/length.

Comment: The whole 'bus' thing in kicad is still mostly decorative until they implement proper bus ports for sheets, too.

Comment: @LorenzoMarcantonio Not quite sure what you mean by "proper bus ports" but more complex bus naming is supported in the upcoming v6

Comment: Yes, buses are becoming more complex but in fact you still splice them out with labels, most of the work is easing the splice out. Proper bus port are hier. sheet port where you enter with *a whole bus* and it's spliced inside the child sheet

Comment: You can currently run a whole bus through a hierarchical pin and break out the components inside the sheet.  Perhaps you are thinking of an older version limitation.